# PHP Headers redirect from external file?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not sure if this is possible or how to implement it.

I have an HTML only file that onload does an ajax request to a PHP file and the PHP script returns the main content of the page. What I'm wondering if its possible is.. when I send the request to PHP can PHP redirect the requesting page to a different page when the session/cookie isn't set?

Comment: You can redirect ajax requests, but if you redirect off-server, you'll run into cross-domain security restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the script to return JSON instead of HTML, you can set a flag that your callback will recognize, redirecting if necessary. With jQuery:

```
<script>
    $.post('/some/script.php', function(response) {
        if (response.redirect) {
            window.location = 'new/location';
        } else {
            // update HTML content
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so a followup question then to get this to work. Can PHP tell the name of the file that sent the request? Ideally I'd have file1.html and file2.html that send essentially the same request but I'd like to redirect to different locations. Is PHP able to using the referrer that the request from file1.html?

Comment: You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to detect where it came from, but you're better off posting some sort of identification in the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the PHP script return a message/value indicating that the session/cookie isn't set and have JavaScript do the redirect? (If a cookie isn't set you can actually check that using JavaScript and skip the whole Ajax/PHP part).